# How do i check if records of this id exists in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, lambda

I have these tables [image]

How do i check if a specific `ActivityTask` activityID and taskID have records in one of the tables  `threeHints` , `questions` and `questionhint`. No activityID and taskID can have records that exist in more than 1 table

I am using entity framework and lambda expressions. I got stuck at how to write the codes to check for records existing in these 3 tables.

Comment: Can you add relevant parts of the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This LINQ query counts the tables that have the record present. Then checks if it's 0 or 1, and adds it to the result set.

```
var activityTasksPresentInOneTableOrNone = ctx.ActivityTasks.Where(at => ((at.ThreeHints.Count > 0 ? 1 : 0) + (at.Questions.Count > 0 ? 1 : 0) + (at.QuestionHints.Count > 0 ? 1 : 0)) <= 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming only one or zero tables has unique pair of (activityID, taskID).

```
public Boolean IsUnique(Int32 activityID, Int32 taskID)
{
    Int32 existsInThreeHints = ThreeHintsRepository.
        Any(hint =>
                hint.activityID == activityID &&
                hint.taskID == taskID) ? 1 : 0;

    Int32 existsInQuestions = QuestionsRepository.
        Any(question =>
                question.activityID == activityID &&
                question.taskID == taskID) ? 1 : 0;

    Int32 existsInQuestionHint = QuestionHintRepository.
        Any(questionHint =>
                questionHint.activityID == activityID &&
                questionHint.taskID == taskID) ? 1 : 0;

    return existsInThreeHints + existsInQuestions + existsInQuestionHint <= 1;
}
```

Comment: you can also just cast the boolean into an integer. 1=true, 0=false.